# How can I modify the rows in my Adapter from my Activity thread?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I've got a `ListView` in on my activities. Upon clicking a button, an `AynscTask` is invoked, which when completed attaches a `BaseAdapter` to that `ListView` in it's `onPostExcecuteMethod` to show the results:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Result> objResults) {
    ListView lvwResults = (ListView) objContext.findViewById(R.id.results);
    lvwResults.setAdapter(new SearchResultsAdapter(this.objContext, objResults));       
}
```

The adapter looks like this on a very simplified note:

```
public class SearchResultsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {    
    private static ArrayList<Result> objResults;
    private Search ctxContext = null;

    public SearchResultsAdapter(Search ctxContext, ArrayList<Result> objResults) {
        this.ctxContext = ctxContext;
        SearchResultsAdapter.objResults = objResults;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctxContext);
        View vewRow = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView tvwName = (TextView) vewRow.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tvwName.setText(objResults.get(position).getName());
        return vewRow;
    }
}
```

From my main activity i.e. the `Activity` that initially invoked the `AsyncTask`, I would like to do some sorting and filtering operations on the list of results in the `SearchResultsAdapter`. How can I do this?

How can I access the adapter rows from my main UI thread because I don't seem to have access to the adapter instance? I also read something about calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you keep the sort you're trying to do on a method on the adapter. Then from the Main Activity you call the method of the adapter (save the adapter instance when creating it).

And don't forget to call notifyDataSetChanged/Invalidated on the adapter method when finishing.

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter with an empty arraylist before you launch the AsyncTask. In post execute add the results to the empty arraylist you used to initialize the adapter. Call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

You can get access to the adapter via ListView's getAdapter() method or you could make the adapter a member variable.